# Azure AD / Graph API - Determine User Source & Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In our organization, we have been inviting guest users to our AAD Tenant to successfully share resources with our B2B partners.  However, we have a fear that there may be some business users that have been oversharing with individuals (e.g. xxx@gmail.com accounts or Business accounts we don't approve of).

We would like to better monitor these scenarios, and I've been able to determine a user's source via the Azure Portal:

[image: External Azure Active Directory]

Here, we can easily see that this particular user is coming from an External Azure Active Directory.

Is there a Microsoft Graph API or Azure AD API where I can get this information, so we can write some automation around this?  Also, is there a way to determine *which* tenant this user is homed in?  I have played around with the Users endpoint a bit, but don't see this information...maybe there is a different endpoint or permissions scope that I need?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get tenant information of a guest user, but we can handle users by domain the user belongs to. you can allow or block invitations to B2B users from specific organizations .Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/allow-deny-list).

Comment: Thanks for the information...I was a bit worried about that.  But you're right, we should be able to use domains.

Do you have any input on being able to find the Source from an API (e.g. External Azure Active Directory vs. Microsoft Account)?